# Web Scraping returning empty data table UiPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I’m using Data Scraping to **scrape** a product Information (i.e Product Name, Url, Price, Model) from a shopping website.

When I search for a product, I want whatever item comes first it scrapes that item’s data and for that purpose I have set maximum number of results to 1. But the problem is sometimes it is returning empty Data table And I cannot figure out why.

What I think is, if the current search result matches those elements that I selected in data **scraping** wizard, it returns the data table and if it doesn’t match it returns empty Data table.
For Example, While selecting elements in Data **scraping** wizard the search results were Samsung monitors. And when I ran the project I searched for Dell monitors, it returned Data table but when I searched for Samsung series or Dell Series it returned empty Data table.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: Is it possible that the table loads dynamically and UiPath scrapes it before it gets populated? You could test that by waiting a few seconds before scraping.

Comment: @MarekStejskal now it is scrapping some data and some not. Like it is scrapping price of the product but not the name of product. It is returning empty name of product.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the website, can you post a link?

Comment: @MarekStejskal Sure. This is the link. [https://www.microcenter.com] 
I'm searching different kinds of monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell what you actually need as output.

But if your output is empty, mostly the reason is one of the following:

- make sure the **timeout** is high enough, set it to 30000 if you are unsure
- set a proper **selector** that has not a bad impact even when the website is being changed for some reason

For me it working properly with a proper timeout and a **flexible selector** with a *.

Comment: timeout is OK to identify the issue but should never be used as it is not a optimized solution.